# Fatal Error C1083 - Cannot open include file: "windows.h": No such file or directory

Tags: c#, .net, path, ikvm

I'm trying to get IKVM to build (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599/how-to-get-ikvm-to-build-in-visual-studio-2008)) but now have encountered a problem not having to do with IKVM so I'm opening up a new question:

When running nant on the IKVM directory with the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt (from the Start Menu), I get the following error:

> ```
>         ikvm-native-win32:
>
>                [cl] Compiling 2 files to C:\ikvm-0.36.0.11\native\Release'.
>
>                [cl] jni.c
>                [cl] os.c
>                [cl] C:\ikvm-0.36.0.11\native\os.c(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such
>                     file or directory
>                [cl] Generating Code...
>
>         BUILD FAILED
>
>         C:\ikvm-0.36.0.11\native\native.build(17,10):
>         External Program Failed: cl (return code was 2)
> ```

I have the Platform SDK installed. What am I missing? I'm sure it's something simple...

**Edit #1** I just checked - I do have the directory containing windows.h on the Path.
**Edit #2** Found the answer (see my answer below): The directory containing windows.h needed to be in the "Include" path variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 can't find windows.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410631/visual-studio-2017-cant-find-windows-h)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK here is the answer I ended up finding: rather than being on the Path, the directory with windows.h (in my case, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include) needed to be set in the Include environment variable.

Comment: So, you have to set the value of the "Include" path variable to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include". If it did not exist you created the "Include" environment variable and set the value to that specified in your answer?

Comment: I'm genuinely asking and also think for prosperity that it is worth being explicit here.

Comment: @JohnDoe - just tried it, some of the Windows SDK's have build command prompts, if you open one and [type `SET`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line), you will see all environment variables, among others `Include=`... which is verbatim as such.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, create environment variable %LIB%, meaning the same - path to all SDKs lib directories