# Compiling Matlab to C++ Problem: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h'

Tags: c++, matlab

I got this weird error when I was trying to compile matlab to C++ using the following command:

```
'mcc -W lib:cshared -d ' clibdir ' -T link:lib ' mfile
```

The error I got was:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'windows.h': No such file or
>   directory

Now, I was using lcc as my compiler ( instead of the Visual Studio one), and I made sure that Windows.h was inside the lcc\include directory (`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2006a\sys\lcc\include`), and yet, I still got the missing `windows.h` error even though I *do* have it inside the `include` folder.

Anyone has any idea why this is so?

Note: I have read similar questions at SO, and found that those problems are related to [include folders not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80788/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-windows-h-no-such-file-or-direct) etc. But I do have the include path set, I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you quote comes from Visual C++, so you're clearly *not* using lcc, and thus it won't make any difference what files you put in lcc's directories. Try running `mbuild -setup` to configure Matlab to use a different compiler command.

If you (or Matlab, on your behalf) are going to run the Visual C++ command-line compiler, then you should run it in a command prompt with all the right environment variables set up, such as the include path. Visual Studio should have put an item on your Start menu for that, or else you can run the `vsvars32.bat` file from within some other console window.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround - in Start Menu you'll find something like `Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express\Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)`

This will start command-prompt with all the environment variables set, including LIB, INCLUDE and so on. Then, **start MATLAB from this command prompt**! E.g.: simply type `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe`. In result, you can call MEX from this MATLAB session.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a workaround; it sounds like what I suggested in my answer nearly three years ago. Does MEX compile the Matlab code into object files for linking with C programs like mcc does? That was the goal, after all. My impression is that mex is for preparing C code so it can be called from Matlab programs, which in this case is the wrong direction.