# List all environment variables from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, prompt

Is it possible to list *all* environment variables from a Windows' command prompt?

Something equivalent to PowerShell's `gci env:` (or `ls env:` or `dir env:`).

Comment: For a description of each, see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

Answer (score 1644, accepted):

Just do:

```
SET
```

You can also do `SET prefix` to see all variables with names starting with `prefix`.

For example, if you want to read only derbydb from the environment variables, do the following:

```
set derby
```

...and you will get the following:

```
DERBY_HOME=c:\Users\amro-a\Desktop\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin\db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin
```

Comment: This prompts me for a name?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: All commands in the Windows shell are case insensitive.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai are you using powershell?  It appears that it has hikacked set with one of its command-lets.  This is one of its less useful features!  I asked a question about disabling this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678521/is-it-possible-to-how-do-you-stop-powershell-using-certain-cmdlets)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `cmd /c`. `/e:on` flag also doesn't help.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work.  This requires command extensions to be enabled.  They are enabled by default on newer windows, but not older ones, and they can be turned off.

Comment: @John Lord: What is "command extensions"? Do you have a reference? Do you mean [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) (PSCX)?

Comment: i do not mean those.  I'm talking about the command prompt (cmd.exe).  Read this:  https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=13988.0
They can break command scripts in some cases when enabled so it's possible a user that does a lot of batch processing has them turned off by default, and they can be turned of on a single-use instance as well in the batch file.
In a specific command instance, it may be required to run this as well:  C:> cmd.exe /E:ON to turn them on.

Answer (score 221):

Jon has the right answer, but to elaborate a little more with some syntactic sugar..

```
SET | more
```

enables you to see the variables one page at a time, rather than the whole lot, or

```
SET > output.txt
```

sends the output to a file output.txt which you can open in [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) or whatever...

Comment: it's actually built in to some functions as well.  Dir for example will page with a /p.

Answer (score 175):

To list all environment variables in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

Or as suggested by user797717 to avoid output truncation:

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

Source: *[Creating and Modifying Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730964(v=technet.10))* (*Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week*)

Comment: Even if I don't use PowerShell because it doesn't work for every cmd command, this is the only solution for a pretty printing (on 2 columns) without big efforts. To achieve the same behavior in cmd, you need something like this `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=="  ...` which becomes very complicated ...

Comment: To avoid output being truncated, I would use the following:
`Get-ChildItem Env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize`

Comment: `gci env:` instead `Get-ChildItem Env:`, easier to remember

Answer (score 93):

Simply run [`set`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490998.aspx) from `cmd`.

> Displays, sets, or removes environment variables. Used without parameters, set displays the current environment settings.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work these days (in 2021)

`
$ set

$ cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1
$ Supply values for the following parameters:
$ Name[0]:
$ Set-Variable: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty array.
`

Comment: set is run in cmd, not Powershell @JayKilleen

Comment: So VERY very true @Grant! +1 But I think the MORE command option was to paginate. :D

@JayKilleen and any other people: ---> **Command Prompt CMD Answer:** `set | more` (or in shortcut: `set | more & pause`) ---> **PowerShell PS Answer:** `gci env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize` -OR- `Get-ChildItem Env: | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize`

Answer (score 24):

## Non expanded variables -

### User variables -

```powershell
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

### System variables -

```powershell
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

## Expanded variables -

### In CMD -

```
SET
```

### In Powershell -

Source - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-windows-powershell-to-display-all-environment-variables/

```powershell
dir env:
```

Comment: `set` by itself doesn't work with Github Actions, but the `reg query` does!

Comment: Sorry @HrishikeshKadam - it doesn't work. Command: `PS C:\Users\User> dir env` Error Message: `dir : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\User\env' because it does not exist... FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `SET` in cmd

To show the current variable, just `SET` is enough

To show certain variable such as 'PATH', use `SET PATH`.

For help, type `set /?`.

Comment: How is this different from existing answers?

Answer (score 11):

Don't lose time. Search for it in the registry:

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
```

returns less than the SET command.

Comment: although that might be true, one difference is that the registry query returns unexpanded `REG_EXPAND_SZ` keys. For example `reg query "HKCU\Environment"` shows me that my `%TEMP%` variable depends on the value of `%USERPROFILE%`, so if that value changes, so would the value for `%TEMP%`. In contrast, `SET` just returns `"C:\Users\mpag\AppData\Local\Temp"`

Comment: Why do you say "don’t lose time"? Isn’t writing "set" in the command prompt faster than "reg query ..."?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the environment variable you just set, you need to open a new command window.

> Variables set with setx variables are available in future command windows only, not in the current command window. (*[Setx, Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc755104(v=ws.11)#examples)*)