# Node.js fails recognizing a new module

Tags: node.js, formidable

[Working on Windows, with node 0.10.5]

I'm trying to build something simple with the formidable module for node. I installed it globally -

```
npm install -g formidable

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
npm WARN engine formidable@1.0.13: wanted: {"node":"<0.9.0"} (current:{"node":"v0.10.5","npm":"1.2.18"})
formidable@1.0.13 C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\formidable
```

Now, the module was installed correctly to the aforementioned directory, but node won't recognize it:

```
D:\Work\Node\Test4>node index.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'formidable'
       Blah blah blah
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Is formidable not being recognized because of the version?
2. If not, what could be the reason for it not being recognized?
3. If so, can I do anything about it other than downgrading node or waiting for a new formidable version?

Comment: How do you require() it?

Comment: var formidable = require("formidable");

Comment: I did find out now that if I copy node_modules to the root dir of the project, it works. But if this is the case, what's the point at the global installation?

Comment: Why would you want to install globally?  Dependencies should be installed locally.

Comment: don't you still need to do an ```npm link formidable``` in your project folder? alternatively do as @josh3736 and install locally

Comment: If I have several projects, why should I install dependencies again and again?

Comment: Because that's how the system is [designed](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) and how other developers expect Node projects to work.  Local dependencies allow you to avoid [dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).  Besides, modules are cached the first time you install them, so it's not like you're redownloading them for every project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, when I've had problems like this it was related to `NODE_PATH`.  My guess is your path `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\formidable` isn't in `NODE_PATH` so even though it's installed "globally" your install can't see it.

See the official documentation about [loading from the global folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) and also checking the value of NODE_PATH by using the [`SET`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line) command on Windows command line.

Comment: Indeed, my NODE_PATH was not set. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I would also suggest you consider why you want a global install, as pointed out in other comments.  A reasonable rule I found repeated a few times here and on other Node sites is "install locally for outward facing apps, install globally for command line utilities based upon node".