# Can't remove some powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I thought I'd go this sorted out in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678521/is-it-possible-to-how-do-you-stop-powershell-using-certain-cmdlets) but I dont seem to be able to disable the **Reset-BC** command.

Normally I would use

```
Remove-Item -force alias:Reset-BC
```

However I just get the following error

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'Alias:\Reset-BC' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -force alias:\Reset-BC
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Alias:\Reset-BC:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNot
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Could anyone explain this or tell me how to get rid of it?

Definitely the thing that annoys me about powershell the most - it just litters your path with loads of rubbish.  On occasion it also actually hides proper applications like where and sc with its stuff aswell which is even worse.  I would use cmd but the lack of autocomplete is painful :(

Comment: Looks like it's already been removed. The message you're getting is because it doesn't exist. If you can still call it, it's not an alias, it's either a function or cmdlet

Comment: @arco444 yeah I thought it might be something like that.  Is there any way to get rid of cmdlets?  Following some stuff in the help it seems like the different things you can delete are linked to `Get-PSProvider` but that doesnt seem to have a cmdlet provider

Comment: I also tried removing it as a function which appears to work occasionally but not if I put it in my powershell profile and I still get it auto completing Reset-BC

Answer (score 0):

You can test existance of Cmdlet:

```
If(get-item alias:Reset-BC) {Remove-Item -force alias:Reset-BC} else {'not exist'}
```

Comment: yeah that tells me it isn't an alias... any idea how to remove it anyway?  Maybe its not possible