# Windows shortcuts and links

Tags: java, c#, windows, io

Where do I go to find all of the Windows shortcuts, or easy-links, or whatever they are called?

I am talking about the ones like `%appdata%`. I want my program to put a shortcut directly on the desktop using one of these commands in my Java program that I will eventually convert to C#. Is there a list of these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all environment variables from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line)

Comment: Also "on the desktop"? Who's? Public, default, or users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Windows Vista and Later

Environment Variable Path

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE% C:\ProgramData

%APPDATA% C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming

%COMMONPROGRAMFILES% C:\Program Files\Common Files

%COMMONPROGRAMFILES(x86)% C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

%COMSPEC% C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

%HOMEDRIVE% C:

%HOMEPATH% C:\Users\{username}

%LOCALAPPDATA% C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local

%PROGRAMDATA% C:\ProgramData

%PROGRAMFILES% C:\Program Files

%PROGRAMFILES(X86)% C:\Program Files (x86) (only in 64-bit version)

%PUBLIC% C:\Users\Public

%SystemDrive% C:

%SystemRoot% C:\Windows

%TEMP% and %TMP% C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp

%USERPROFILE% C:\Users\{username}

%WINDIR% C:\Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to refer to what Windows calls *SpecialFolderConstants* (or sometimes referred to *Common Folders*). However, not all of these are available as *environment variables* (as you mentioned `%APPDATA%`).

See these links to get further information

- .NET [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Win32 [ShellSpecialFolderConstants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Common File and Folder Locations](http://campus.mst.edu/cis/desktop/documentation/pc/win7_x64/common_file_locations/)

To get a list of your environment variables and check which common folders are defined as variables you can use PowerShell and run

```
cd env:
dir
```

You could place something on the user's desktop by starting with something like this:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

However, for creating desktop shortcuts, your question might already be answered by [Create shortcut on desktop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897655/create-shortcut-on-desktop-c-sharp)
.