# Clang++ 4.0.0 compilation error in windows

Tags: c++, windows, clang, visual-studio-2017, llvm-clang

I'm using clang 4.0.0 compiled from source on windows 10 (32-bit OS, x86 processor). I'm trying to compile my cpp code to llvm ir code of the format ll. 
Here's a sample code which fails to compile using clang:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <mapi.h>
#include <memory>
#include<stdio.h>

/* Function to calculate x raised to the power y */
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
}

/* Program to test function power */
int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    unsigned int y = 3;

    printf("%d", power(x, y));
    return 0;
}
```

This is just a sample code, but it's the same behavior across all c++ code which include the listed header files.
I use the following command to compile it to llvm ir code:

```
clang++ -S -emit-llvm assiral.cpp -o assiral.ll
```

On compilation I get the following error:

```
C:\Sample>clang++ -emit-llvm -S assiral.cpp -o assiral.ll
In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\cmath:617:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xtgmath.h:9:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xtr1common:204:22: error:
use of undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
struct _Is_integral<char16_t>
^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xtr1common:210:22: error:
use of undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
struct _Is_integral<char32_t>
^
In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\exception:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\type_traits:6:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstddef:257:2: error: 'auto'
  return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
auto _Unfancy(_Ptrty _Ptr)
  ^
  In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:7:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0:8:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\limits:612:33: error: use of
  undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
  template<> class numeric_limits<char16_t>
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\limits:902:33: error: use of
  undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
  template<> class numeric_limits<char32_t>
  ^
  In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:7:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\utility:7:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\iosfwd:254:21: error: use of
  undeclared identifier 'char16_t'
  struct char_traits<char16_t>
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\iosfwd:263:21: error: use of
  undeclared identifier 'char32_t'
  struct char_traits<char32_t>
  ^
  In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:7:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0:10:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility:698:2: error:
  'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
auto _Unchecked_n(_Iter _Src, _Diff)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility:742:2: error:
  'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
auto _Unchecked_n_backward(_Iter _Src, _Diff)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility:1142:12: error:
  deduced return types are a C++14 extension
constexpr decltype(auto) _Operator_arrow(_Iterator&& _Target, false_type)
  ^
  In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:7:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:6:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0:356:2: error:
  'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
auto _Const_cast(_Ptrty _Ptr)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0:366:2: error:
  'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension
auto _Const_cast(_Ty * _Ptr)
  ^
  In file included from assiral.cpp:3:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\includem:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ostream:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\ios:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocnum:10:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\streambuf:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xiosbase:6:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xlocale:8:
  In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\stdexcept:7:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:75:2: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Start_at; ; ++_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:119:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Min_value(_Start_at, _Hay_size - _Needle_size); ; --_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:144:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Min_value(_Start_at, _Hay_size - 1); ; --_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:169:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Start_at; _Match_try < _End; ++_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:188:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Min_value(_Start_at, _Hay_size - 1); ; --_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:213:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Start_at; _Match_try < _End; ++_Match_try)
  ^
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xstring:233:3: error:
  statement not allowed in constexpr function
  for (auto _Match_try = _Haystack + _Start_at; _Match_try < _End; ++_Match_try)
  ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
```

What I expect after running the command is to have the bytecode file generated (.ll file). I've seen many posts where they introduce a flag : '-fms-compatibility-version=19' along with the command. However the flag added gets flagged as an unknown argument. I'm working with MSVS 2017. Maybe I'm using this flag wrong. But I've been at this impasse for a day now. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include a minimal compilable example.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question.  With a slightly modified source to remove Windows specific headers it compiles fine under Linux.  So that's where I would begin troubleshooting.  Try rearranging your includes and removing ones that are not needed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It doesn't get to a stage of compilation due to the header issues.

Comment: I'm working against your minimal example, which does not require the headers `windows.h`, `tlhelp32.h`, or `mapi.h`.  It also does not require `fstream` or `memory`, but I've verified your minimal example with those headers anyway (because they're standard.)

Comment: Thanks your immediate response. The headers are needed as part of the actual code I'm trying to compile. As I've mentioned before : " This is just a sample code, but it's the same behavior across all c++ code which include the listed header files." I have a source code which uses these header files and need to be compiled in windows. I'm clear on the fact that the issue is regarding the header files specific to windows :) The troubleshooting is where I requested help. Rearranging includes didn't do much for me :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not run Windows, so I am unable to help further.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adding the correct path to the header files in the environment variable INCLUDE. Most of my errors were resolved once I fixed the paths. This includes the error where compiling a c++ file which references certain headers like windows.h gives a file not found.

Link on how to do the same : [List all environment variables from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-command-line)

You can also fix another issue which is :

```
link fatal error lnk1104 cannot open file 'libcmt.lib'
```

by setting the LIBPATH environment variable to point to the right location of the libcmt.lib file. I found mine at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib
```

These trivial issues left me spending quite a few days to figure out. Hope this saves someone the same trouble.