# how to command variables values from conftest.py to pytest in cmd.exe

Tags: python, cmd, pytest

in bash "env" and in terminalX "env -S" work, in cmd "env" is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.

for example:

on Linux :(. venv) ~ rootdir> $ env "browser.config.browser_name = firefox" pytest tests / file.py

on MacOS :(. venv) ~ / rootdir> env -S "browser.config.browser_name = firefox" pytest tests / file.py

but on Win: (. venv) ~/ rootdir> ...**?**... "browser.config.browser_name = firefox" pytest tests / file.py

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I got it. Please have a look at the answer [List all environment variables from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-the-command-line) then.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just meant, what to replace the command env in Windows command line because cmd.exe says env is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file.

Comment: for example in bash command env communicate "variable=values" which are in conftest.py to pytest. in cmd.exe not.