# env : The term 'env' is not recognized as the name

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, environment-variables

I am new to coding and I am learning about environment variables in python using pycharm. I am trying to hide my API KEY in the terminal for basic security however when I type env into the terminal this is the response.

env : The term 'env' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- env
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

How can I fix this? How can I fix the path or find the path?

Comment: are you just trying to find out the current environment variables? try `SET`

Answer (score 2):

`env` is not a program installed by default on Windows, you're probably thinking of the `env` command commonly used on Linux and Unix based systems to display your environment. The equivalent Windows command is `Get-ChildItem Env:` for PowerShell, and `SET` in command prompt (Thanks @ᴓᴓᴓ!)

Comment: `Get-ChildItem Env:` in powershell and `SET` in cmd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327495/list-all-environment-variables-from-the-command-line

Comment: thanks for the response crock  I will check it out!